# Alternating ratios on featured image

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image-resizing

I have alternating post classes with different sizes (.even & .odd). What I would like however, is that the ratio on the featured image is also alternating. So, I would like the ratio for .even featured images to be 1:1 and ratio for .odd to be 3:2. Is is possible to crop the images that way with css? I've tried adding the following code to my functions.php, but it gives me only one ratio for all posts.

```
if('even'){  // only on frontpage
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
   set_post_thumbnail_size( 300, 300, true );
   }

   }else if('odd'){
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   set_post_thumbnail_size( 1000, 500, true );
   }
}
```

More code from the functions.php

```
 add_filter( 'post_class', 'sk_even_odd_post_class' );
 function sk_even_odd_post_class( $classes ) {

 global $wp_query;

 if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) {
 $classes[] = ($wp_query->current_post % 3 == 0) ? 'odd' : 'even';
 }

 return $classes;

}

set_post_thumbnail_size( 1000, 400, true );
```

CSS:

```
.odd.entry {
    border: 0px solid #288eb0;
}

.odd.entry img{
    width:100%;

}

.even.entry {
    border: 0px solid #fff;
}

.even.entry img{
    height:auto;
    width:400px;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could crop them with CSS but it will be a pseudo crop, you'd have to use `overflow` and `position`, and adjust accordingly. I think you probably need to create two custom image sizes via `add_image_size` and then assign them according to class. But I'd probably hang on for someone more intelligent than me to provide a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach i.e. Register Image sizes on your theme as image cropping is done when image is uploaded to media library and not on the run time.

So you can achieve it this way:

1. Register Two images sizes in your theme's functions.php file:

   add_image_size( 'odd-thumb', 1000, 500, true );

   add_image_size( 'even-thumb', 300, 300, true );
2. Now in your front-end templates' loop where you are adding Odd/Even logic classes. And calling the thumbnail, call only the thumbnails which matter i.e. following code (using your code as base as I dont know how your theme is setup, but your will get idea what needs to be changed:)

   ```
    if('even'){  
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
     the_post_thumbnail( 'even-thumb' ); 
               }

     }else if('odd'){
      if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
           the_post_thumbnail( 'odd-thumb' ); 
                   }
        }
   ```

Comment: Code formatting is getting out of hand. If someone can fix it please. I am trying again meanwhile.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I'm working in a genesis child theme if that's any help. 

I can't make it work in functions, which is why I was hoping it was possible to do the cropping in css... I'm adding what little css code I have above.

Comment: @moiety paste your custom code where you are placing the images (by editing your original question, show all code where you are adding ODD/EVEN classes also in php logic and where you are calling the featured image), yes the code I shared for image size registering should work fine in Genesis.

Comment: I only have the odd/even classes in the functions.php. I think the image registering is working fine, but it just wont add the correct size to the correct place...

Comment: Please share your functions.php code which is dealing with the odd/even and also what code is dealing with the the outputting the featured images?

Comment: I've added what I could above. Hope it's helpful.